# Check my proof that $\operatorname{Proj}\ k[x_0,...,x_n]/I$ is a reduced projective $k$ scheme for $I$ radical

Tags: algebraic-geometry, solution-verification, commutative-algebra

I was doing Ravi's FOAG book exercise 5.3 E which asks me to prove that :

$\operatorname{Proj}\ k[x_0,...,x_n]/I$ is reduced projective $k$ scheme for $I$ is radical homogeneous ideal

---

To show it's projective $k$- scheme is easy, since $k[x_0,...,x_n]/I$ is a finite generated $k$ algebra generated by $x_0,...,x_n$.

The problem, therefore, lies in showing it's reduced, since it's covered by $D(x_i)$ (as $x_i$ are generators). and $D(x_i)$ is affine, the problem reduces to show that the coordinate ring of $D(x_i)$ is reduced, then taking localization will preserve the reducedness. therefore we needs to figure out what $$((k[x_0,...,x_n]/I)_{x_i})_0 \tag{*}$$

is, where the inner subscript ${x_i}$ means taking localization at $x_i$ the outer subscript $0$ means the degree zero part of it. And it's sufficient to prove (*) is reduced.

For $I$ is radical iff $(k[x_0,...,x_n]/I)$ is a reduced ring. Since localization preserves reduces, we have $(k[x_0,...,x_n]/I)_{x_i}$ is reduced. Since the degree zero part is a subring of it, and the subring of the reduced ring is reduced therefore we have (*) reduced.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: I think it's correct. It's a nice proof. And it should be mentioned in the last paragraph that localization preserves reduceness too?

Comment: Thank you onriv, I add more explanation in the last paragraph.

Comment: This is fine, but there's no need to have the statement about $I=0$ in there.